# What would I need to add to the HTML of a Workflow Flexi task to redirect after approval

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I need to bounce the user back to the list after they've approved a Workflow task. I've got to add the url to the HTML of the flexi task task description to redirect but can't see where I'd add it? Can anyone help?

```
<font face="Arial"><span id="NWRTEReference1">item doc number Infrustucture     
 Specfication form for item doc number <span id="NWRTEReference3"><a class="ms-rtestate-write" contenteditable="false" onclick="selectThis(this);" href="javascript:void(0);" reftext="%7BItemProperty%3ADocument_Nimber%7D" link="false" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red">Document Number</a></span>&#160;for the Server <span id="NWRTEReference4">
<a class="ms-rtestate-write" contenteditable="false" onclick="selectThis(this);" href="javascript:void(0);" reftext="%7BItemProperty%3Aserver_name%7D" link="false" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red">Server Name</a>&#160;has been sumbitted for your approval <br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update this part  `href="javascript:void(0);"` to  `href="www.google.com"`

full code, had to update it as you were missing some html:

```
<font face="Arial">
    <span id="NWRTEReference1">item doc number Infrustucture Specfication form for item doc number </span>

    <span id="NWRTEReference3">
        <a class="ms-rtestate-write" contenteditable="false" onclick="selectThis(this);" href="www.google.com" data-rel="back" reftext="%7BItemProperty%3ADocument_Nimber%7D" link="false" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red">Document Number</a>
    </span>

    &#160;for the Server 
    <span id="NWRTEReference4">
        <a class="ms-rtestate-write" contenteditable="false" onclick="selectThis(this);" href="www.google.com" data-rel="back" reftext="%7BItemProperty%3Aserver_name%7D" link="false" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red">Server Name</a>
        &#160;has been sumbitted for your approval <br/>
    </span>

</font>
```

code above redirects to google. You could try `data-rel="back"` which should take you back once when the a link is clicked and if no back info is available then it uses the href instead.

Comment: That did work like a dream, but now every time I go into the code the HTML reverts to what was originally there and over writes what I've put in?

Comment: is this in nintex?

Comment: nintex can be a pain sometimes. just make sure that you save the flexi task and then the workflow aswell. Otherwise recreate the flexi task with the correct code should fix the issue